# How to get ttl Redisson key value from Redis client

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis, redisson

Unable to Retrieve TTL value

```
RedissonClient client = Redisson.create(config);
RMapCache<String, String> map = client.getMapCache("demoMap");
map.put("abc", "xyz", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Am able to get the value of key as hget demoMap"\"abc\""

But when I tried with TTL "\"abc\"" it is showing (integer) -2. I know -2 status is key does not exists. But when I use HGETALL demoMap/ hget dempMAp "\"abc\""

Able to see key and values.

Unable to retrieve TTL values.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use `RMapCache.remainTimeToLive()` method.